# Recurring Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron, javascript-objects

I know that this has been asked a lot but it is been days of researching and I am still stuck with the same error. I cannot seem to find the perfect solution.

So I have a `button` that I am trying to power with a `JS` function on an **external** file(`scorecards.js`) located in `js folder`..

```
<a id="generateScorecardBtn" class="btn orange lighten-1 btn-large" onclick="generateScorecard(document.getElementById('uploadAppPerfLog').value, document.getElementById('uploadDbPerfLog').value);">
```

But I still get this error when I click the button

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: generateScorecard is not defined
```

Even though I referenced it correctly on the HTML `<head>`

```
<script src="js/scorecards.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Kindly help me investigate this. I also compile the app using the `node.js` command prompt.

Thank you very much!

**Link** to `scorecard.js`: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzZ5wr0I2306VGJzTUZTMDY4eHc

Comment: Where is `generateScorecard()` definition ?

Comment: in your  `js/scorecards.js` file wrap code inside `$(document).ready(function(){..});` (except from function)

Comment: but my `external js` file only contains `function { }` codes that I plan to use on my `index.html`.. Is that what _except from function_ supposed to mean above? @AlivetoDie

Comment: @MayankPandeyz `function generateScorecard(param1, param2)` is located in my `scorecards.js` file inside a `js` folder.

Comment: Hi @MayankPandeyz @Alive to Die I have included the link of the `js` file in the question. Kindly help me investigate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This function:

```
onclick="generateScorecard(...);"
```

should have to be in the global scope *(window)* as you are directly referencing it. If error says *Uncaught ReferenceError: generateScorecard is not defined* That means it is not available in the global scope as you are guessing it to be.

You need to check if the function is been put inside a namespace like:

```
var $$global = $$global || {};

$$global.generateScorecard = function(a, b){};
```

If such is the case then the function will be available as

```
onclick="$$global.generateScorecard(...);"
```

Comment: Hi @Jai I tried the solution and it is now throwing `Uncaught ReferenceError: $$global is not defined`. In my external `js` file, I only have blocks of `function { }` code to be used in `index.html` though.

Comment: @JPaulPunzalan That I gave you a fake global namespace. There might be something else in your condition. Can you post your `scorecards.js` code in the question?

Comment: Hi @Jai I have uploaded the `js` file on Google Drive. Kindly check the edit below the question. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @Jai Any findings?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess (wrong, see below) is that the js file is not being loaded, because "js/" is not in the current directory. Check you have the correct relative path.

But, either way, as this is an Electron app, you should open the chrome dev tools, and look to see what console errors you are getting, or look at the Network tab to see if it is loading.

Look at [toggleDevTools](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-make-developer-tools-appear/16232/8) to have the chrome dev tools appear when you start-up, or come up when you press a key.

P.S. I did that, and your code has a syntax error! I.e. the path is correct, but the file contents are invalid, which is why it doesn't exist when you click the button.

In `processDataToDictionary()` you are missing the "/" at the end of a regex.

```
csv.split(/\r\n|\n);
```